# how to get start and end rows for null records in Table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have table like

```
DateTime    V1        V2 
------------------------
1/1/2001    100       200
1/2/2001    null      null
1/3/2001    null      null 
1/4/2001    100       300
1/5/2001    null      null
1/6/2001    null      null
```

I want to find gapdays  like starting row date as SDate and ending row date is EDate when the column values v1 and v2 are null

```
SDateTime     EDateTime    Days
1/2/2001      1/3/2011       2
1/5/2001      1/6/2001       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a DBMS so this is an ANSI SQL solution:

```
select min(datetime) as start_date, 
       max(datetime) as end_date, 
       max(datetime) - min(datetime) as days
from (
  select datetime,
         v1,
         v2, 
         sum(case 
               when v1 is null and v2 is null then null
               else 1
             end) over (order by datetime) as group_flag
  from foo
) t
group by group_flag
order by 1
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/12fdb/1

Comment: @user2710631: what is a "*ur*" reply? (Sorry, english is not my native language)

Comment: Hi I am using SQL Server 2008 But wen try to use above script i am geeting error like "Incorrect syntax near 'order'. In the table havig datetime column having date and time also ex: 1/1/2001 10:10:00:000

Comment: @user2710631: SQL Server 2008 does not support a running sum with window functions. That's the reason why you should have stated your DBMS right from the beginning.

Comment: Any alternative solution for that?

Comment: No idea. Window functions in SQL Server (prior to 2012) are extremely limited.